# Missing settings in GNOME control center installed in Ubuntu MATE

Tags: gnome, mate, google-drive, gnome-control-center

I installed GNOME Control Center following [this instructions](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/use-google-drive-ubuntu-16-04-linux-desktops) to access Google Drive in Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS (MATE desktop environment 1.12.1)

The problem is GNOME Control Center is only showing language support, printers, firewall setup and backups... not online accounts or other settings.

This is what I get:

```
~$ gnome-control-center gnome-online-accounts 

** (gnome-control-center:5744): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher landscape-client-settings (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:5744): WARNING **: Invalid categories System;Settings; for panel software-properties-gtk.desktop

** (gnome-control-center:5744): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher ubuntuone-installer (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:5744): WARNING **: Could not find settings panel "gnome-online-accounts"
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I did. I followed the instructions.
`sudo apt install gnome-control-center gnome-online-accounts`
(I also try "sudo apt install gnome-online-accounts" alone)

Comment: Probably it's not feasible with MATE, the linked article doesn't say it will wok with MATE. It seems it's about making it work in vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity). To make Google Drive integration work, you'll most likely need Nautilus. But MATE uses Caja as the file manager.

Answer (score 4):

I found [other solution](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/google-drive-and-onedrive-integration/12815/8) to get GNOME Online Accounts working on MATE.

On Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS we need the following

1. install one package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-online-accounts
   ```
2. And then set-up Google account in `gnome-control-center`:

   ```
   env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center online-accounts
   ```
3. Afterwards you will get your Google Drive in the *Devices* section of *Caja* named *username@gmail.com*. If you open this folder in Caja, then its location would be `google-drive://username@gmail.com`.  This folder is synced automatically. But Google Docs will be opened in the browser.

Hope this helps.